# Decrypting .P7M File with Key (.pem) using OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, openssl, smime, decryption

My knownledge about security is limited so I need some help here.

**The Question**

> I want to Decrypt a .P7M file using its private key (.pem). I would prefer to use OpenSSL for this.

**Tried so far**

```
OpenSSL smime -decrypt -in "Secret.p7m" -inkey "Key.pem" > Result.txt
```

**Error**

```
unable to load signing key file
7548:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib
.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
error in smime**The P7M File**
```

> Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; name="smime.p7m";
>   smime-type=enveloped-data
>  Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
>   
> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
>   
> Content-Description: S/MIME Encrypted Message
>
> BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA

Comment: "Cannot seem to get it to work". What command did you use, and what was the result? Any error messages?

Comment: Edited post with code sample i used

Answer (score 2):

Your decryption command is correct.

It seems there's something wrong with your key file. Does it really start with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and end with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` (mind the exact number of dashes)? Or is it perhaps DER encoded which requires you to add `-keyform DER` your decryption command line?

BTW: You can check the integrity of the key itself with `openssl rsa -in Key.pem`

Comment: Checking the integrity is fine. The output gives me -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY---- BLABLABALABALBALABALBA -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this same issue and Lupo's answer is on the right track. You can try converting the key using a command like:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <key file.p7m> -out <key_file.pem> -nodes
```